# Save data in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

how is it possible to save the data the user is inserting, that I only print:

```
print(c(input$buttonNext,randomNumber,input_radio))
```

This should not be just printed, but it should be available to me later. My plan is, that people evaluate my plots and then I see for each user the buttons he clicked for each plot.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  actionButton("buttonNext", "Next"),

  radioButtons("radio", "Your Decision:",
               choices = c("No Decision" = 'NoDec', "Yes" = 'yes', "No" = 'no'),
               selected = 'NoDec'),

  plotOutput("TimeSeriesPlot")
)


server <- function(input,output,session) {

  clickNext <- reactive({
    isolate(input_radio <- input$radio)
    randomNumber <- input$buttonNext
    print(c(input$buttonNext,randomNumber,input_radio))
    return(randomNumber)
  })

  observeEvent(input$buttonNext,
               {
                 updateRadioButtons(session,'radio',selected = -1)
               })

  output$TimeSeriesPlot <- renderPlot({ 
    i <- clickNext()
    plot(i)
  })

}
shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach is the typical for any similar web app, you can:

- Save data as files in a dedicated folder, either in csv format or rds (R compressed format), probably using a combination of user name, time, session etc. in the file name.
- Use some kind of a database connection (anything like SQLite, mysql, PostgreSQL would do. Here you can decide on best design (e.g. single table for all users, table for each users etc.) depending on application.

Ultimately the decision will depend on the complexity of the application, the amount of data, concerns about data integrity, portability, environment etc.

Exploiting some of the many nice features of R, you could sore as per your request, the parameters specified by the user, but you could even store the actual resulting plot.

Ideally this would require a blob field in a db, but in principle you could build a list of lists, where one of the entries are the plot parameters, and the other is the actual plot (then save everything in a single rds file.

This is a sample implementation. You can save data in an RDS file, or use the alternative implementation (commented out here) that allows you to save the data once when you kill the app.

```
library(shiny)

# this is not strictly necessary, but is the way I prefer to define an emply data.frame
resultData <- data.frame(times=character(), inputs=numeric(), random=numeric(),
                     decision=character())

ui <- fluidPage(

  actionButton("buttonNext", "Next"),

  radioButtons("radio", "Your Decision:",
           choices = c("No Decision" = 'NoDec', "Yes" = 'yes', "No" = 'no'),
           selected = 'NoDec'),

  plotOutput("TimeSeriesPlot")
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {

  clickNext <- reactive({
    isolate(input_radio <- input$radio)
    randomNumber <- input$buttonNext
    print(c(input$buttonNext,randomNumber,input$radio))
    return(randomNumber)
  })

  observeEvent(input$buttonNext,
           {
             updateRadioButtons(session,'radio',selected = -1)
           })

  output$TimeSeriesPlot <- renderPlot({

    i <- clickNext()
    a <- plot(i)
    results <-   data.frame(times=Sys.time(),inputs=input$buttonNext,random=clickNext(),
  decision=input$radio)

    # with <<- you  make sure the variable is updated outside of the scope of the function
    resultData <<- rbind(resultData,results)
    saveRDS(resultData, file = "data/resultData.rds")
  })

  # alterantive way to save data, when the app is ended
  # session$onSessionEnded({
  #   saveRDS(resultData, file = "data/resultData.rds")
  #   stopApp
  # })
}
shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)

# analyse <- readRDS(file = "data/resultData.rds")
```

Please let me know if you'd like me to expand any of the above.

Comment: I added 
resultData <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 1)) and in clickNext added     resultData <- rbind(resultData,c(input$buttonNext,randomNumber,input_radio))
    saveRDS(resultData, file = "data/resultData.rds") . But I am not sure. Looks strange to me. I dont know if I can use resultData and then it always overwrites the user input and does not append it at the end. I assume I'm going in the wrong direction ...

Comment: Short second question. I am new here. Usually the querist respond on an answer with a comment?

Comment: I've added an example based on your code.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you. I will test it. And this resultData.rds will be saved then for each user and the user has to upload the file somehow to the server then or can I see all data of each survey in my shinyapp account later? I intent to collect in the order of 100 surveys of different user. Thank you a lot

Comment: Well, This is designed so that you get a single file for `all` users (once you  add a textInput box r for users to type their name and add a `user` field to the resultData / results data.frames). Once you run this app on shiny server, each user will write in the attached file all the appropriate data (e.g. user name, timestamp and session, as well as any survey data).  If you plan to have >100 users, while this solution would still work fine, it would possibly better to write onto a DB.